# Multiple rows into columns with column values group by columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to transform rows to column group by:

[image]

Desired result would be like this:

[image]

Comment: It's Dynamic So we can't assume column Name  Values fixed

Comment: Rather than posting picture, post your data as DDL and DML statement, and don't forget to includes your attempts. There's plenty of examples on how to do this on SO, so what were wrong with those answers?

Comment: @ShankarKumar . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You seem to be assuming that your data has an ordering.  Your transformation doesn't make sense unless a column has the ordering.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a column that specifies the ordering, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when columnname = 'SupplierGSTin' then value end) as SupplierGSTin,
       max(case when columnname = 'DocumentNumber' then value end) as DocumentNumber,
       max(case when columnname = 'SupplyType' then value end) as SupplyType
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by columnname order by ?) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by rownum;
```

The `?` is for the column that specifies the ordering.